# Jitterbit consuming outbound messages

Tags: workflow, soap

I'm working with the Jitterbit application to try and consume the salesforce SOAP outbound message to send case data over to bugzilla.

I don't know much about SOAP but been reading http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_summary.asp to try and create a proper SOAP message for the Jitterbit service.  I've created my a sample file of the outbound message, and uploaded the wsdl to Jitterbit.  I've been working a bit with Jitterbit support already and waiting to hear back on this new issue I've run into.  (The reason why i've created this file is I'm waiting for my machine to be in the DMZ so Salesforce can send it the message)

Issue: In Jitterbit when I try and load my sample file I receive this error -

> at line 2, column 2 The node "/root" has undefined value or
>   subelement(s): Body at line 2, column 2 null

I'm sure I'm missing some syntax in the file which defines one of the sub-elements but I've been staring at this for some time.

SOAP Sample file I created to simulate the SFDC outbound message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <soapenv:Body>
     <notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
      <OrganizationId>0000000opwS</OrganizationId>
      <ActionId>04k30000000L6QPAA0</ActionId>
      <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <EnterpriseUrl>https://na1-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/22.0/00D30000000opwS</EnterpriseUrl>
      <PartnerUrl>https://na1-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0/00D30000000opwS</PartnerUrl>
      <Notification>
       <Id>NotificationID</Id>
       <sObject xsi:type="sf:Case" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
        <sf:Id>0013000000ooziWAAQ</sf:Id>
        <sf:CaseNumber>7777</sf:CaseNumber>
        <sf:Description>New York</sf:Description>
        <sf:Status>US</sf:Status>
        <sf:Subject>Open</sf:Subject>
        <sf:IsDeleted>false</sf:IsDeleted>
       </sObject>
      </Notification>
     </notifications>
     </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldnt recommend trying to handcraft a message.

You can use [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to construct mock soap messages to test your Jitterbit service while you're waiting for your machine to be setup. You can import the wsdl into a soapUI project and it can generate mock messages and even make a call out to the Jitterbit service.

Comment: OK I'll admit I didn't create this from scratch, I used this example, [post from another user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987673/how-can-i-consume-a-soap-message-with-namespace-from-salesforce-in-php)

Comment: Try soapUI, just import the wsdl and you will have a sample soap request message in no time.